# OWASP TOP 10 - 4. Insecure Direct Object References - other way then ESAPI in JSF 1.2 + JAVA + SEAM

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2, seam2, owasp, esapi

Is there anything already integrated in JSF 1.2 or SEAM 2.2.2 to prevent [A4-Insecure Direct Object References](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A4)

I know the ESAPI functions to do it, but i don't want to include another framework into my project if not necessary, is there anything build into JSF or SEAM?

Comment: I don't think there is anything readily available but ESAPI is open source and this is a relatively simple problem to fix using an IndirectObjectReferenceMap

Check out http://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/main/java/org/owasp/esapi/AccessReferenceMap.java

Comment: Hey Chris, i know the EASPI stuff, thats i was asking if there is a simpler, built in solution  for handling the problem, but out of the box! ESAPI is perfect for this, but i just want to see some other alternatives! but thanks for your reply anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several alternatives:

1. Verify access to the secured resource in your SQL statements
2. The indirect object hash map is a terrifically simple construct that is literally 10 lines of code. Just re-implement, and be careful of your source of randomness
3. Change your taglibraries to do what ASP.net does, which is to
   validate checkboxes, radio groups, selects etc that have constrained
   input, have the same value as one of the potential inputs that was
   sent out (i.e. if you have "1", "2", and "3", that the parameter is
   one of those three values. JSF 2 and Rich Faces still don't bring you up to ASP.NET 2.0 levels of basic software engineering.
4. Using s:validateForm from Faces integration to perform programmatic inspection.

Honestly, I think (2) is the best alternative as I know bringing in ESAPI for J2EE requires stubbing out quiet a bit for a few lines of code. Why it needs a custom filebaseauthenticator to do DOR mapping is beyond me. I aimed for looser coupling in ESAPI for PHP, but it's been a while for me hacking on ESAPI for J2EE.